# api request json what to use jquery angular, etc

Tags: jquery, json, angularjs, node.js, facebook

I am new with api's I would like to do a eco game with Facebook, for london and amsterdam. 
but I have to obtain some data from api in each city. 
I have read a little and i think i can request info in client side of the app and process it and after send this info to an eco app in Facebook.what i have to do.

what is the best system to do it, jquery, angular, others...?

also I would like to avoid a server, i can do, but if i keep simple is better for that reason better
what platform??, jquery , angular?.
if i have not other choice I would use a nodejs server.

Do you know examples and or tutorials to learn about it??.

thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have to make AJAX requests to the Facebook API, you should be good without a backend technology. You most probably need a backend if you need to store any information in a database, but it'd be good if you can provide more information about the capabilities that the application should have so we can give you more advice.

Given client-side applications, you don't actually need any library/framework to make AJAX requests, as [this is built in the DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

That being said, libraries such as jQuery, or a framework such as AngularJS will make the process easier by providing nice high level interfaces plus other goodies to keep your application as maintainable as possible.

About the technologies you mentioned in your question, you can't really compare jQuery to AngularJS, as their purpose is quite different.

jQuery is a library that attempts to remove (or reduce) inconsistencies between browser implementations for things like HTML manipulation, event handling, AJAX requests, etc.

AngularJS, on the other hand, is a full featured framework to build web applications, that provides a templating solution, a router, data bindings, directives and other goodies that you'd expect on a complete solution product to build web applications.

Depending on the complexity of your application, you might be good by just using jQuery and doing HTML manipulation directly, otherwise it might be worth to invest some time into a framework's steeper learning curve to build a more solid product more easily.

Also notice that in case you want to go for a framework, AngularJS is not the only choice. You can check:

- [Ember](http://emberjs.com/).
- [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/).
- [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/).
- And many, many more that you can find about at [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/).

And go with the one you agree on it's principles.

I've been working professionally with AngularJS for a while, so I'd recommend the following book as a very good comprehensive introduction: https://www.ng-book.com/.

Comment: thanks so much my friend. i have to check it all and decide, but i will have to include a backend. with node. i will send info by email. all the best and 1000 thanks.